# Access controls in VSTO word addin

Tags: ms-word, vsto, ms-office, ribbonx

I have walked thru the microsoft tutorial on adding buttons to a ribbon in MS word using XML markup. I have added this XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab idMso="TabAddIns">
        <group id="MyGroup" label="TestAddin">
          <editBox id="myEditBox" label="Script" OnChange="TextFieldChanged"/>
          <button id="testButton" label="Test Button"
             screentip="Test" onAction="OnTestButton"
             supertip="Blah blah."/>         
        </group>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

How to access the text inside the editbox when clicking on the button?

I tried

```
public void TextFieldChanged(Office.IRibbonControl control)
{
}
```

and

```
public void TextFieldChanged(string text)
{
}
```

but both without success. How should the callback looks like to get the content of the EditBox?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the `onChange` callback for the `editBox` control: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_standards/ms-customui/7b552756-a970-466d-b7c2-ee5bbe171e34

Answer (score 0):

It has to take both, the IRibbonControl and a string like

```
public void TextFieldChanged(Office.IRibbonControl control, string text)
{
    Word.Range range = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.Range;
    range.Text = text;
}
```

https://shulerent.com/2011/08/16/changing-the-value-of-an-editbox-office-ribbon-control-at-runtime/

PS: It does NOT fire when text is changing as the name implies. It fires when enter is pressed!